# Redirecting from document root to folder with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

My directory structure is like this and my document root is /

```
/
.htaccess
    /public
```

This is all on my local xampp server.
The server is set up to listen for mydomain.local and in my hosts file I have pointed mydomian.local to localhost.

I am using the following .htaccess code and it works fine when using mydomain.local as the address.

The problem that I am having is that it does not work when I am using localhost/mydomain as the address

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

How can I get it to work when using localhost/mydomain as the address?

The reason for this is because I am trying to register service worker but they only work over https or localhost.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the expected behavior on url rewriting ? Do you mean that locahost/mydomain = mydomain.local or awaiting localhost/public/index.php?path=mydomain that will be the logical result of your setup. Aside this, are you using virtual hosts or aliases ?

Comment: @Bertrand localhost/mydomain/page = mydomain.local/page = mydomain.local/index.php?path=page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

root folder .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

public folder .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may also keep a single .htaccess file at root by changing a bit your rewrite rule to add an optional `mydomain/` in match but not using it :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Add optional group
RewriteRule ^(mydomain/)?(.*)$ /public/index.php?path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
# Same with a non capturing group
RewriteRule ^(?:mydomain/)?(.*)$ /public/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

By the way, you can use [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to check effects of rules rewriting on url

Comment: Whats the group and non capturing group mean?

Comment: You define a capturing group with brackets and can use it as a replacement value : firrst bracket is available as $1 and so on. You can avoid capturing by prepending ?: to the bracket content. By doing (*.) you capture anything and it's usable as $1 (your way). In my example, i've put both way with managing a (mydomain/) first group